# How to make cabal to be found in a straigthforward nix-pill 8.1 imitation?

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix

The cabal isn't found on the following example and the question is, how to correct the example so that cabal is found.

This example is very straigthforward modification of [the nix pill 8.1](https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/generic-builders.html). On `nix-repl`, typing `:l <nixpkgs>` and then `"${cabal-install}"` gives a path to the store where cabal-install is and it contains sub-dirs with bin there containing cabal-executable. I.e.

```
> /nix/store/pathtocabal-install/bin/cabal -v
cabal-install version 2.0.0.0
compiled using version 2.0.0.2 of the Cabal library
```

Below you should find the files corresponding to the the "make c" example.

With them, the

```
> nix-build hello.nix
```

doesn't work. It first tells to build "these derivations" and then says that

```
hello_builder.sh: line 2: cabal: command not found
```

I'm suspecting that $cabal-install/bin is a wrong way to refer to cabal but on `nix-repl` its store-path is found.

hello_builder.sh  is even shorter than in the c-example. Note that installation part is still missing (first the builder should be made to find the cabal).

```
export PATH="$coreutils/bin:$ghc/bin:$cabal-install/bin:$binutils/bin"
cabal build hello
```

hello.nix - maybe the binutils is not needed.

```
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
derivation {
  name = "hello";
  builder = "${bash}/bin/bash";
  args = [ ./hello_builder.sh ];
  inherit binutils coreutils ghc cabal-install;
  src = ./hello.cabal;
  system = builtins.currentSystem;
}
```

hello.cabal - in `nix-shell` with cabal-install and ghc, this works.

```
name:                hello
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.24

executable hello
  main-is:             hello.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base              >=4.9 && <4.10
```

hello.hs

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello there!"
```

---

Late additions:

By adding `echo $PATH` to the builder, we can see that the path is not correct. It is `/nix/store/...coreutils-8.28/bin:/nix/store...ghc-8.0.2/bin:-install/bin:/nix/store/...binutils-2.28.1/bin`. There the `$cabal` is turned into an empty string and it is not referring to `$cabal-install`. Thus there is no correct store-path for the cabal-executable.

This answers part of the why-part of the question and how to correct it remains. And the open why-part is, why `inherit cabal-install` cannot be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `inherit cabal-install;` is that `cabal-install` is not a valid variable name in BASH. Nix converts the keys in the set provided to `derivation` into variables in BASH.

Instead of `inherit cabal-install;` you can do something like `cabal_install = cabal-install;` and then use `cabal_install` in your builder.